# Wrong decimal result when adding and dividing numbers in loop

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    float sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("1/%d +",i);
        sum=sum+1/i;
    }
    printf("= %f",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I've kept the `sum` variable `float` to see the values after decimal. But the result doesn't appear to be correct. `000000` is shown after decimal. Why is this happening? What should I do to get the correct value without changing other variable's datatype? When I change other variables to float datatype,the answer remains correct.

Comment: Google for integer division

Comment: What are we supposed to make out of this tiny screenshot? And how can we copy/paste parts of your code into the answer? Please post it in plain text.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    float sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("1/%d +",i);
        sum=sum+1/i;
    }

    printf("=  %f",sum);
    return 0;





}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `1` and `i` are integers, the expression `1/i` is evaluated as integer.

Therefore, if `i > 1` then `1/i == 0`.

You can solve this using `float(1)/i` or `1/float(i)` or `float(1)/float(i)`.

Comment: thanks bro,It worked perfectly and completely cleared my confusions